# GET file content from external JSON file

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, ajax, json

I am trying to get file content from external JSON file but I keep getting null on the alert.

**JS:**

```
function getText() {
    var result = null;
    var file = 'file.json';
    $.ajax({
        type: 'get',
        data: 'data',
        dataType: 'json',
        async: false,
        success: function() {
            var ranData = data[Math.floor(Math.random() * data.length)];
            result = ranData;
        }
    });
    alert(result);
}
```

**External file:**

```
var data = [
  ["a", "word 1"],
  ["e", "word 2"],
  ["i", "word 3"],
  ["o", "word 4"],
  ["u", "word 5"]
]
```

It works fine when I use `data` array in the same file instead. What am I doing? Any help will be appreciated!

**UPDATE:**

```
function readFiles() {
        var result = null;
        var file = 'dictionary.js';
        $.ajax({
            url: file,
            type: 'get',
            data: 'data',
            dataType: 'script',
            async: false,
            success: function(data) {
                var randomData = data[Math.floor(Math.random() * data.length)];
                result = randomData;
            }
        });
        alert(result);
 }
```

Still getting null value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to pass `data` argument to success callback function, but also you forgot to set url parameter to which the request is sent:

```
 function getText() {
    var result = null;
    $.ajax({
        urL: 'file.json',
        type: 'GET',
        data: 'data',
        dataType: 'json',
        async: false,
        success: function(data) {
            var ranData = data[Math.floor(Math.random() * data.length)];
            result = ranData;
        }
    });
    alert(result);
}
```

And one more thing. You really shouldn't be using `async:false` in your ajax because synchronous ajax will completely freeze the browser until ajax request is finished. You should process your data inside success callback. Also I noticed that in your success callback you're checking for array length `data.length`, well this probably won't work since you're expecting to get back data from server in JSON format (you set `dataType` options to `json`)

Comment: the url wasn't set and the file contains invalid data.

Answer (score 0):

The file you are trying to load is not in the JSON format, its javascript code. Remove the `var =` statement and everything should be fine.